# In SQL Server, I am creating a social network database and got error in responding to requests

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a stored procedure to respond to the friend request, but this gives me a syntax error

```
CREATE PROC RESPOND_REQUEST @id1   INTEGER,
                            @id2   INTEGER,
                            @reply BIT
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT R
      FROM   Requests R
      WHERE  r.reciever_id = @id1
             AND r.sender_id = @id2

      SET R.reply = @reply
  END
```

Comment: Please explain what the stored procedure is intended to actually do.

Comment: Does the procedure mean to have an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: As an aside, reciever is actually spelled 'receiver'. Unlikely, but may be the source of your syntax error.

Comment: [SQL UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: Post the error occurred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the procedure should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RESPOND_REQUEST -- always use dbo prefix
  @id1 INT, 
  @id2 INT, 
  @reply BIT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE dbo.Requests -- always use dbo prefix
    SET reply = @reply
    WHERE reciever_id = @id1 -- fix this typo - i before e, except after c
      AND sender_id = @id2;
END
GO
```

[About the dbo prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Also, you should rename the parameters, instead of generic `@id1` and `@id2` why not call them what they are, `@receiver_id` and `@sender_id`? Just giving them numbers seems unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i don't get the use of 'SET NOCOUNT ON;'

Comment: @user3100088 I have a blurb about it here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand, please bear in mind (given your own advice in the blog post) that you don't know the schema that the asker is using, so a blanket statement of 'always use dbo' is just plain wrong - something like 'always clarify schema names' is much better and wholly great advice. Also, for reference, I believe the rule concerning 'i and e' is actually broken more times than it is correct in the english language, it's certainly far from universal

Comment: @Dave thanks, but 99.999% of the time, when schema isn't mentioned at all, it's dbo. I made a guess. And for the word receiver, the rule stands - I was suggesting to correct that word by adding a comment in a code sample, not trying to teach an English course. Both of these things as unnecessary, helpful asides **in addition to solving the problem**. Any more nit-picking you'd like to add?

Answer (score 1):

To update in MS SQL Server use

```
UPDATE Requests
SET    Reply = @Reply
WHERE  receiver_id = @id1
AND    sender_id = @id2
```